# jQuery Multiple Image uploaders

Tags: jquery, ajax

What's the best jQuery multiple image uploader that you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I like [Valums AJAX upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) but [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) is pretty popular and definitely worth checking if it corresponds to your requirements.